# Tab is Default on but still cannot see the tab by default

Tags: custom-object, profile, tab, custom-profile

I have created a custom object Pay and a custom profile Manager. 
Then created a tab Pay for object. The custom profile Manager has permission on the object Pay and also for tab Pay - default on setting has been saved.

Yet when I log in as a user with profile Manager, i cannot see the tab Pay. I can click on the + symbol and add it but I am under the assumption that if default on is saved for a tab, by default the tab should appear.

Answer (score 4):

Setting up the tab correctly in the profile makes it available under the "+", but the set of tabs displayed in the tab bar is controlled by the currently selected app in the top right hand corner of the screen.

To modify the set of tabs shown when an app is selected, go to Setup -> Create -> Apps and then edit the app you want your tab to appear in and move your tab to the "Selected Tabs" list (in which you can also choose the tab order).

Comment: Its already been included in the Selected Tabs on the App

Answer (score 0):

Please check the button called "Customize My Tabs" under the "+", This button is used to Change how tabs display on your screen.

Comment: When I click on Customize My Tabs, I can see the tab in Available Tabs. But my doubt is, if Tab setting is Default On, by default the tab should be visible in Tabs

Comment: Yes. The tab settings that you have given is at app level. But the tabs that are selected in "Customize My Tabs" is at user level.

Comment: if there are 20 users, how does the admin setup tabs for all 20 users

Comment: Admin will give the access to all 20 users. The individual user will login into their salesforce and can customize their own tabs. Giving access to all the users is what admins job.Admin can setup the tabs for all users at profile or permission sets. What tabs to be shown on the screen,depends on the user interest. The user can also customize his/her tabs  at Setup-->My Personal Information-->Change My Display-->Customize My Tabs (or) My Settings-->Display & Layout-->Customize My Tabs.

Comment: Is there a way for Admin to set default visible tabs for all 20 users, so each individual need not go through this exercise

Comment: I was wondering the same. Anyone has answer to the above question by @Guddan?

Answer (score 0):

Check the profile. Once on the profile page, click edit and search for the tab's name in the 'Custom Tab Settings' section. Chances are the tab is set as 'Tab Hidden'. Change the setting to whatever you need.